# MessageBox and while loop C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, messagebox

I'm modifying existing C# code in order to pilote a piston. Every 30ms, I have a direct feedback of the position of this piston, through an event. The value is stored in a global variable I use to get the current position of the piston.

What I'm trying to achieve: for a given distance input (A->C), I want the piston to travel at full speed for 95% of the distance (A->B), and then slower for the remaining 5% (B->C).

I have access to a command that defines the speed and the destination of the piston : pos(velocity, destination).

However, if I write that code:

```
pos(fullSpeed,B);
pos(reducedSpeed, C);
```

the piston directly goes from fullSpeed to reducedSpeed

I tried to use a while loop to compare the current position of the piston with the goal destination, however, upon entering the while loop, the variable storing the piston position does not update anymore.

However, I noticed that by throwing a MessageBox in between, the position value keeps on getting updated, and I can simply click "ok" to launch the second command.

```
pos(fullSpeed,B);
MessageBox.show("Wait");
pos(reducedSpeed, C);
```

I would like to know why the "while" loop stops the update of the position variable but the MessageBox does not. I mean, as long as I don't click the "ok" button, the box is here preventing me from doing anything, which for me ressembles a while loop behaviour. Is there another way for me to do this instead of the MessageBox ?

I have little to no knowledge when it comes to C# and no support. I have tried to look in the documentation, but I did not find an answer (I have probably missed it). Any lead is more than welcome.

**EDIT**: I have no documentation for that code, and it is barely commented. Here is what I gathered (really hope it helps):

To move the piston, taht function is called:

```
MyEdc.Move.Pos(control, speed, destination, ref MyTan);
```

control simply define what we pilote (a distance or a load, it is an enum), and I have no idea what MyTan does. Only thing I know is that the MyEdc.Move.Pos returns an error code.

If I look at the definition of "pos", I am redirected to class

```
public DoPEmove Move;
```

containing among other things:

```
public DoPE.ERR Pos(DoPE.CTRL MoveCtrl, double Speed, double Destination, ref short Tan);
```

DoPE.ERR is also an type enum. However, I cannot reach the definition of a function named "Pos". Coud it be within the .dll included ?

The following is the code that allows me to access the position of the piston (without the global variables):

```
private int OnData(ref DoPE.OnData Data, object Parameter)
    {
      if (Data.DoPError == DoPE.ERR.NOERROR)
      {
        DoPE.Data Sample = Data.Data;
        Int32 Time = Environment.TickCount;
        if ((Time - LastTime) >= 300 /*ms*/)
        {
          LastTime = Time;
          string text;
          text = String.Format("{0}", Sample.Time.ToString("0.000"));
          guiTime.Text = text;
          text = String.Format("{0}", Sample.Sensor[(int)DoPE.SENSOR.SENSOR_S].ToString("0.000"));
          guiPosition.Text = text;
          text = String.Format("{0}", Sample.Sensor[(int)DoPE.SENSOR.SENSOR_F].ToString("0.000"));
          guiLoad.Text = text;
          text = String.Format("{0}", Sample.Sensor[(int)DoPE.SENSOR.SENSOR_E].ToString("0.000"));
          guiExtension.Text = text;
        }
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Which is called using

```
MyEdc.Eh.OnDataHdlr += new DoPE.OnDataHdlr(OnData);
```

I realise how little I know on how the soft operates, and how frustrating this is for you. If you think this is a lost cause, no problem, I'll try Timothy Jannace solution, and if it does not help me, I'll stick with the MessageBox solution. I just wanted to know why the MessageBox allowed me to sort of achieve my objectif, but the while loop did not, and how to use it in my advantage here.

Comment: What is the code of pos()? Is that an asynchronous method? What did you try to locate in documentation?

Comment: Without knowing anything about `pos`, we can't really say anything. Apparently, it is an asynchronous call. Is there a return value (or an overload that notifies you if the position is reached)? How is the position update designed? Apparently, it runs on the same thread as your `while`. So, the `while` is just blocking that update. Again, without knowing anything about the library, it is impossible to tell something helpful.

Comment: please provide the code of pos()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to use a while loop to compare the current position of the
>   piston with the goal destination, however, upon entering the while
>   loop, the variable storing the piston position does not update
>   anymore.

While you are in the `while` loop, your app can no longer receive and process the feedback **event**.

One possible solution would be to use [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async)/[await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) like this:

```
private const int fullSpeed = 1;
private const int reducedSpeed = 2;

private int currentPistonPositon = 0; // global var updated by event as you described

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int B = 50;
    int C = 75;

    pos(fullSpeed, B);

    await Task.Run(() =>
        {   // pick one below?

            // assumes that "B" and "currentPistonPosition" can actually be EXACTLY the same value
            while (currentPistonPositon != B) 
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
            }

            // if this isn't the case, then  perhaps when it reaches a certain threshold distance?
            while (Math.Abs(currentPistonPositon - B) > 0.10)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
            }
        });

    pos(reducedSpeed, C);
}
```

Note the `button1_Click` method signature has been marked with `async`.  The code will wait for the while loop inside the task to complete while still processing **event** messages because of the `await`.  Only then will it move on to the second `pos()` call.

> Thank you for your answer ! It works like a charm ! (good catch on the
>   EXACT value). I learnt a lot, and I am sure the async/await combo is
>   going to be very usefull in the future ! – MaximeS

If that worked well, then you might want to consider refactoring the code and making your own "goto position" method like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int B = 50;
    int C = 75;

    GotoPosition(fullSpeed, B);
    GotoPosition(reducedSpeed, C);
}

private async void GotoPosition(int speed, int position)
{
    pos(speed, position);

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (Math.Abs(currentPistonPositon - position) > 0.10)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
        }
    });
}
```

Readability would be greatly improved.

You could even get fancier and introduce a **timeout** concept into the while loop.  Now your code could do something like below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int B = 50;
    int C = 75;

    if (GotoPosition(fullSpeed, B, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(750)).Result)
    {
        if (GotoPosition(reducedSpeed, C, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500)).Result)
        {
            // ... we successfully went to B at fullSpeed, then to C at reducedSpeed ...
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Piston Timed Out");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Piston Timed Out");
    }

}

private async Task<bool> GotoPosition(int speed, int position, TimeSpan timeOut)
{
    pos(speed, position); // call the async API

    // wait for the position to be reached, or the timeout to occur
    bool success = true; // assume we have succeeded until proven otherwise
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Add(timeOut); // set our timeout DateTime in the future
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50); // give the piston a chance to update maybe once before checking?
        while (Math.Abs(currentPistonPositon - position) > 0.10) // see if the piston has reached our target position
        {
            if (DateTime.Now > dt) // did we move past our timeout DateTime?
            {
                success = false;
                break;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25); // very small sleep to reduce CPU usage
        }
    });
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It works like a charm ! (good catch on the EXACT value). I learnt a lot, and I am sure the async/await combo is going to be very usefull in the future !

Comment: Does the piston report its position via the event **all of the time**, or does it only report in response to a `pos()` call and then only until it has stopped moving?

Comment: Thank you so much for your edit, I'll implement it still today!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using events you are probably having concurrency issues. Especially with events being raised every 30ms!

A very simple way to handle concurrency is to use a lock object to prevent different threads from using contested resources simultaneously:

```
class MyEventHandler
{
    private object _lockObject;

    MyEventHandler()
    {
        _lockObject = new object();
    }

    public int MyContestedResource { get; }

    public void HandleEvent( object sender, MyEvent event )
    {
        lock ( _lockObject )
        {
            // do stuff with event here
            MyContestedResource++;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that is very simple and by no means perfect in every scenario. If you provide more information about how the events are raised and what you're doing with them people will be able to provide more help.

**EDIT:**

Using that signature you posted for the Pos method I was able to find documentation on the library you are using: https://www.academia.edu/24938060/Do_PE

The reason you only see the method signature when you goto definition is because the library has been compiled into a dll. Actually, it probably wouldn't be that useful to see the code anyway because it looks like the library is a C# wrapper around native (c or c++) code.

Anyways, I hope the documentation is helpful to you. If you look at page 20 there are some pointers on doing movement. This is going to be a challenge for a new programmer but you can do it. I would suggest you avoid using the event handler to drive your logic and instead stick with using the *synchronous* versions of commands. Using the synchronous commands your code should operate the same way it reads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Timothy ! If I understand what is happening is your code, I can't seem to be able to properly implement it (very limited skill here, sorry). The fact that I don't understand much of what is happening here (especially all the events and where they are called), does not help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs on my problem. I have been looking for the doc, but even the machine manufacturer did not have it so I did not try too hard to look for it online. I'm sure this is going to be helpful, and I'll follow your advice and try to stick with  sync commands as much as possible!

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you'll want to do is add a call to:

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

This will allow your application to process posted messages (events), which will allow that global variable to be updated.

> I just wanted to know why the MessageBox allowed me to sort of achieve my objectif, but the while loop did not, and how to use it in my advantage here.

The reason that works is because you're giving the WndProc a chance to process events which have been sent to the application. It's not an intended feature of that call to `MessageBox.Show();`, but it is a consequence. You can do the same thing with a call to `Application.DoEvents();` without the interruption of the message box.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations ! Simply adding `Application.DoEvents()` actually worked ! I will go for @Idle_Mind solution because it makes the code easier to read, but thank you very much for taking the time to explain me what was happening and for offering a solution.